# Equivalence between squared-norm and norm inequalities

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, radicals

Let $a,b,c \in \mathcal{L}_2^n(\mathbb{R}_+)$, and let $\|\cdot\|_2$ be the norm in $\mathcal{L}_2^n(\mathbb{R}_+)$.

Suppose that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ (independent of $a,b$ or $c$) such that
$$\|a\|_2^2 - \|b\|_2^2 \leq -\varepsilon\|c\|_2^2.$$
Then, can I say that there exists $\tilde{\varepsilon} > 0$ (again independent of $a,b$ or $c$) such that
$$\|a\|_2 - \|b\|_2 \leq -\tilde{\varepsilon}\|c\|_2$$
and if so, how could I prove it?

I tried using concavity of the square root function, as well as the fact that $\sqrt{a+b} \leq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$, both to no success. Any help or indication in the direction of a proof (or a proof that this is false, for that matter) would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT:

To clarify, by $\mathcal{L}_2^n(\mathbb{R}_+)$ I mean
$$\mathcal{L}_2^n(\mathbb{R}_+) = \left\{f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}^n \;\middle|\; \int_0^\infty\!f(t)^Tf(t)\,dt < \infty\right\}$$

Just to add some more information, we can say that  $a = f_1(c)$ and $b = f_2(c)$, with $f_1,f_2$ bounded operators from $\mathcal{L}_2^n(\mathbb{R}_+)$ into itself. Then, there exist $0 < \gamma_1 < \infty$ and $0 < \gamma_2 < \infty$ such that $\|a\| \leq \gamma_1\|c\|$ and $\|b\| \leq \gamma_2\|c\|$.
Using this, I get that
$$\|a\|_2^2 - \|b\|_2^2 \leq -\varepsilon_2\left(\|a\|_2^2 + \|b\|_2^2\right)$$
where $\varepsilon_2 = \min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2\gamma_1^2},\frac{\varepsilon}{2\gamma_2^2}\right\}$.
Then, after some manipulation, we have that
$$\|a\|_2 - \|b\|_2 \leq -\varepsilon_3\left(\|a\|_2 + \|b\|_2\right)$$
with $\varepsilon_3 = \min\left\{\sqrt{1+\varepsilon_3} - 1,1 - \sqrt{1-\varepsilon_3}\right\}$. But then I don't know how to go back to $\|c\|$ to conclude...

Comment: If the typographical difference between $||a||$ and $\|a\|$ is not conspicuous to you, look at the difference between $||a|| ||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|.$ I edited this question accordingly.

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by $\mathcal L_2^n$? Is this the set of functions $u: \Bbb R_+ \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ such that each component $u_i\in \mathcal L_2$?

Comment: @bames Please see edited question, hopefully things are clearer now. Thank you for your remark.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to be more specific with dependencies. But, without restrictions, you have 
$$
\|a\|_2^2-\|b\|_2^2=(\|a\|_2-\|b\|_2)(\|a\|_2+\|b\|_2). 
$$
So 
$$
\|a\|_2-\|b\|_2\leq- \left(\frac{\varepsilon\|c\|_2}{\|a\|_2+\|b\|_2} \right)\,\|c\|_2
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for some $\tilde{\varepsilon}$ that do not depend on $a,b$ or $c$, though. Please see edited question.